# Access 2007 Combobox displaying wrong results from table

Tags: sql-server, combobox, ms-access-2007

I have four ComboBoxes that are linked to SQL Tables and then they are linked to a log table.

The problem I have is that the combobox is displaying the correct options but only logging the ID value.

So say I have a combobox called Location and it has 3 locations:

```
Cape Town
Dallas
London
```

The ComboBox is showing those 3 choices in the drop down but when the choice is logged it will only return the values 1,2 or 3 and not the cities

Here is the row source:

```
SELECT Location.ID, Location.Location FROM Location ORDER BY Location.ID, Location.Location;
```

But when I tried swapping the Location and ID order around it then displays the values and then logs the cities.

Also this is only an issue since I linked the tables to SQL when they were local tables it worked fine.

I must be missing some sort of search field in the source query, can anyone help me please

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, I had to take ID out of the equation completely and then add into extra location columns in my row source

It ended up like this:

SELECT Location.Location, Location.Location, Location.Location FROM Location ORDER BY Location.Location;

To be honest, I stumbled across this and it works. So that will do for me!

Comment: I suggest doing some reading about the properties of multi-column comboboxes. For a start e.g. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/comboboxes/bind_index2010.php

Comment: So true. As you should be able to imagine, only _one_ occurrence of Locaction.Location is needed.